# Need assistance with non-overlapping text

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing, p5.js

I am trying to create random text which does not overlap each other. I'm really new to coding and I tried to use Shiffman's non-overlapping circles tutorial to come this far, but I am still not able to create the required output, please help.

```js
var textFunc = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 400);

  // Lets make sure we don't get stuck in infinite loop
  var protection = 0;

  // Try to get to 500
  while (textFunc.length < 700) {
    // Pick a random Position
    var textDisp = {
      x: random(width),
      y: random(height)
    }

    // Does it overlap any previous circles?
    var overlapping = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < textFunc.length; j++) {
      var other = textFunc[j];
      var d = dist(textDisp.x, textDisp.y, other.x, other.y);
      if (d < textDisp.x && textDisp.x < other.y && other.y) {
        overlapping = true;
      }
    }

    // If not keep it!
    if (!overlapping) {
      textFunc.push(textDisp);
    }

    // Are we stuck?
    protection++;
    if (protection > 10000) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // Display all the Text
  for (var i = 0; i < textFunc.length; i++) {
    fill(random(255), random(100), random(0));
    noStroke();
    text('hahah', textFunc[i].x, textFunc[i].y);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? If so post that too. And also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get yourself comfortable.

Comment: Sure, I will look into it. But I did not get any error on the console and it seems to run properly. 
I am unsure if the logic being used here (i.e. calculating distance between the text) is actually correct. I would like some direction in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum distance depends on the width and the height of the text. The radius is the half length of the diagonal though the area which is covered by the text. The length of the diagonal can be calculated by [`Math.hypot()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot):

```js
diagonal = Math.hypot(width, height)
```

Define the height (size) of the text by [`textSize()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textSize):

```js
let textHeight = 12;
textSize(textHeight);
```

Add the text to `textDisp` and determine the width of the text by [`textWidth()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textWidth) and calculate the radius:

```js
let text = 'hahah'
let w = textWidth(text)
var textDisp = {
    x: random(width),
    y: random(height),
    t: text, 
    r: Math.hypot(w, textHeight) / 2
}
```

So you can calculate the radius and use the same algorithm as in the [Ellipse No Overlap.](https://gist.github.com/nick3499/fe7387e95a73393b5a3972f351d3f860)  example:

```js
var d = dist(textDisp.x, textDisp.y, other.x, other.y);
if (d < textDisp.r + other.r) {
    overlapping = true;
}
```

To rotate the text randomly, you've to add a random angle to `textDisp`:

```js
var textDisp = {
    // [...]
    a: random(180)-90,
    // [...]
}
```

Use [`translate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate) too move the center of the text to (0, 0). Rotate the text by [`rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate), where [`radians()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/radians) converts the angle from degree to radians. Finally move the text to its location, by `translate()`.
[`push()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) respectively [`pop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop) saves and restore the current transformation:

```js
push();
translate(textFunc[i].x, textFunc[i].y);
rotate(radians(textFunc[i].a));
translate(-textWidth(textFunc[i].t)/2, textHeight/2);
text(textFunc[i].t, 0, 0);
pop();
```

See the example:

```js
var textFunc = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(700, 400);

    // Lets make sure we don't get stuck in infinite loop
    var protection = 0;

    let textHeight = 12;
    textSize(textHeight);
    
    // Try to get to 500
    while (textFunc.length < 700) {
        // Pick a random Position
        let text = 'hahah'
        let w = textWidth(text)
        var textDisp = {
            x: random(width),
            y: random(height),
            a: random(180)-90,
            t: text, 
            r: Math.hypot(w, textHeight) / 2
        }

        // Does it overlap any previous circles?
        var overlapping = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < textFunc.length; j++) {
            var other = textFunc[j];
            
            var d = dist(textDisp.x, textDisp.y, other.x, other.y);
            if (d < textDisp.r + other.r) {
                overlapping = true;
            }
        }

        // If not keep it!
        if (!overlapping) {
            textFunc.push(textDisp);
        }

        // Are we stuck?
        protection++;
        if (protection > 10000) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Display all the Text
    for (var i = 0; i < textFunc.length; i++) {
        fill(random(255), random(100), random(0));
        noStroke();
        push();
        translate(textFunc[i].x, textFunc[i].y);
        rotate(radians(textFunc[i].a));
        translate(-textWidth(textFunc[i].t)/2, textHeight/2);
        text(textFunc[i].t, 0, 0);
        pop();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the help!
Would there any way that i can randomly orientate the rotation of the text?